# How can we set the visibility of a button placed inside a Infragistrics Windows Grid control

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a form where i have used Infragistics windows grid control to display the data. 
In this, i have placed a button on one of the cell. I want to set its visibility either True or False based on the row condition. 
I have handled the **InitializeRow** event of **UltraWinGrid** control and able to disable the button. But i am unable to set the button's visible to False.

Comment: Have you tried asking on http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/default.aspx ?

Comment: Have you ever asked Infragistics for help? Not a rewarding experience. Half of the time they can't even answer (given that you at least provide some kind of code sample with a reasonable explanation of your issue) and when they do answer it isn't that helpful...Better off asking Google for help versus asking them

Answer (score 2):

```
UltraGridRow row = ...

row.Cells[buttonCellIndex].Hidden = true;
```

(I'm using the `UltraGrid` in Infragistics NetAdvantage for Windows Forms 2008 Vol. 2 CLR 2.0.)

Answer (score -1):

At first yo must achieve the row and cell ,
then use findControl method and assign that to a button ,
now the button is in your hand . you can set the visibility :)